# How do I use my 2TB Internal harddrive with my internal SSD?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, ssd

Recently bought a new computer, custom build.
I have two internal hard drives and one external.
I have a Samsung Evo 850 500GB and a Western Digital BLACK SERIES 2TB 3.5" 7200RPM Internal Hard Drive. I'm currently booting from the Evo, but I don't know I can use my 2TB hard drive in conjunction, so I can put all my 'useless' data on the 2TB (Pictures, Movies, etc.) HDD and then use the SSD for stuff that matters. Was also going to cut up a small partition of the HDD for a different OS

Thanks, guys!

Comment: Just hook it up to the SATA port and provide power to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what operating system are you on? If you're using Windows I'd recommend moving the desktop, documents, pictures, videos, etc. onto one of the partitions of the 2TB hard drive. Then you can use the other partition for installing other OS. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand how to do this? The hard drive doesn't show up in the sidebar of the file explorer. I've got the SSD(Local) and my external.

Comment: @Recon Press the Windows key then search for 'computer management' then select 'disk management'. I'm not sure if there's a pop up about hard drive partitioning of whether you can choose MBR (master boot record) or GPT. Choose GPT. I'll send you further instructions once you complete this. :D

Comment: I'm on the screen; there's only one disk, Disk 0. I can choose the option GPT. I'll do that now.

Comment: I see the 'un-used' Disk with my 2TB on it. Disk 0 it was, it's onlineand unallocated. What should I do?

Comment: @Recon Are you plugging in the drives directly onto the motherboard?

Comment: I believ 'Disk 0' is the disk I'm talking about. What do I do from there? Create a simple volume?

Comment: Yes I believe it is connected to motherboard.

Comment: Yes you create a simple volume.

Comment: Is it possible for you to PM/chat me? Thanks. If you can't: What do I format the partition with? NFTS since it'll be used by windows only right?

Comment: @Recon absolutely. But...how...?

Comment: Usually after a few comments it asks you to move to a chat, anyways! NFTS right? Sorry, just wanna make sure I don't screw up anything.

Comment: @Recon yep for Windows. Btw, (if yes) which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: Win 10 Home Edition, installed from USB.

Comment: @Recon ok. Then just create an NTFS volume and you should be good to go. If you still don't see the drive, go back to disk management and right click on the volume you created. Then choose "assign drive letter" and assign one. Good luck!

Comment: Your welcome :) mind voting this answer useful or sth for me? :P

Comment: I can't upvote because I lack the 15 rep requirement, sorry :)

Comment: @Recon yea it's ok :D

Comment: Please move the relevant information from the comments into your answer.